# Remove all user accessrights from mailbox in exchange using powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

This removes all FullAccess accessrights from a mailbox for a certain user.

```
Remove-MailboxPermission -identity MyMailbox -user SomeUser -AccessRights FullAccess
```

This removes SendAs accessrights

```
Remove-MailboxPermission -identity MyMailbox -user SomeUser -AccessRights SendAs
```

Is there something I can do to remove ALL accessrights in one go, so I do not have to explicitly have to remove every single kind of accessright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with:

(assumes input $alias with samaccountname/identity)

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $alias | ForEach-Object {Remove-MailboxPermission -identity $_.Identity -user $_.User -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -confirm: $false}
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $alias | ForEach-Object {Remove-MailboxPermission -identity $_.Identity -user $_.User -AccessRights ReadPermission -InheritanceType All -confirm: $false}
$Permissions = Get-Mailbox -identity $alias | where {($_.Identity -like "*")} | Get-ADPermission | Where-Object { ($_.ExtendedRights -like "*send-as*") -and $_.User -notlike "*AUTHORITY*" }
if ($Permissions) 
{
    $Permissions | ForEach-Object{ Remove-ADPermission -identity $_.Identity -user $_.User -ExtendedRights "Send As" -confirm:$false }
} 

$mb = Get-mailbox -Identity $alias
$mb.GrantSendOnBehalfTo = "CN=SomeAdminAccount,CN=Users,DC=ourdomain,DC=local"

Set-Mailbox -Identity $alias -GrantSendOnBehalfTo $mb.GrantSendOnBehalfTo
```

Could be made a bit more elegant, but good gets the job done.

Also works using remote powershell, something that often seems to fail with creative" solutions using piping.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity MyMailbox -User SomeUser -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
```

or ( not tested )

```
$ar = "FullAccess", "SendAs", "ExternalAccount", "DeleteItem", "ReadPermission", "ChangePermission", "ChangeOwner"
Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity MyMailbox -User SomeUser -AccessRights $ar -InheritanceType All
```

Comment: I can confirm that this does work, I've done it this way before. You can skip the variable and the quotes by putting the list of rights to remove directly in the arguments: `Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity MyMailbox -User SomeUser -AccessRights FullAccess, SendAs,ExternalAccount,DeleteItem,ReadPermission,ChangePermission,ChangeOwner -InheritanceType All`

Answer (score 0):

Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity hppo.us@something.com -User vcx@something.com  -AccessRights FullAccess -Confirm: $false

Remove-RecipientPermission hr-stuttgart@something.com -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee Paul.Rumiz@something.com   -confirm: $false

Comment: The OP said he wants to remove all the rights for a mailbox *without* using separate commands for each right. He already knows how to do it with separate commands.